# How to merge two or more solr search result?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, ranking

I have multiple instances of my application. each application is pointing to its own solr for document indexing.

I am working on a **unified search**, where user hit a query in the search bar and the relevant documents from all the instance should be ranked based on relevance.

Right now I have implemented a solution based on Round Robin fashion.

**For example**, I have 2 instances, **Ins-1** with **solr-1** and **Ins-2** with **solr-2**.
Ins-1 has 1K docs and Ins-2 has 5K docs. when I hit any query, the query will fetch X number of docs from solr-1 and X number of docs from solr-2.
I am showing those 2X documents in round robin fashion. But it is not a best way to show the search result.
I am looking for a solution where I can re-rank those 2X documents based on relevance to the search.

Comment: Are the schema identical on both instances? Are they single cores, or are they cloud instances with collections?

Comment: yes, schema identical on both instances. They are single cores and they are cloud instances with collections.

Comment: @MatsLindh: Any suggestion?

Comment: The regular approach is to create a dummy core, with the same schema, then use [manual sharding through the `shards` parameter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/distributed-search-with-index-sharding.html#DistributedSearchwithIndexSharding-ExecutingDistributedSearcheswiththeshardsParameter) to search both cores at the same time as a unified result set. But if you're using cloud mode, that might be hard to coordinate as the number of nodes grow.

Comment: @MatsLindh: Can we re-rank those 2X documents using Lucene API / Solr API or some other algorithm after fetching from different solr?

Comment: If you assume that the distribution of documents are identical (.. enough) across both nodes, then you can take the result from both and reorder it manually based on their scores - you'll want to try to avoid score normalization in that case, but I don't remember if that's possible from user space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should merge the two instances into single instance. You can import data from one instance to another. Solr Admin UI has a tab 'DataImport' to import data from one collection to another.

Comment: I don't want to merge two instances into a single instance and its a business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

here doc1 and doc2 are two invidual responses from solr you can do it in JAVA

```
  SolrDocumentList appendResponse(SolrDocumentList doc1,SolrDocumentList doc2) {
    SolrDocumentList documentsList=new SolrDocumentList();
    for (SolrDocument solrDocument:doc1) 
    { 
            documentsList.add(solrDocument);
    }
    for (SolrDocument solrDocument:doc2) 
    { 
            documentsList.add(solrDocument);
    }

    return documentsList;
}
```